# keep getting error unknown colum in field list in sql whilst trying to insert column

Tags: sql, error-handling

My query

```
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_ACE', 2, 12, 9950, 400);
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_BETA', 2, 15, 11250, 450);
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_GAMMA', 3, 21, 12550, 500);
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_DELTA', 4, 25, 15950, 550);
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_EPSILON', 4, 30, 19950, 600);
INSERT INTO CABIN(NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST) 
VALUES ('SUN_CAB_ZETA', 4, 36, 24550, 650);
  
SELECT * FROM CABIN;
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE CABIN 
(
    CABIN_TYPE CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    CDESCRIPTION CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    PURCH_DATE DATE NULL, 
    DEL_DATE DATE NULL, 
    CABIN_NAME CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (CABIN_TYPE) 
);
```

Comment: Could you pls share table definition? Please add DBMS as well for precise answer. From error msg, it seems, one of these columns `NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST` doesnt exist in table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE CABIN 
 (CABIN_TYPE CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 CDESCRIPTION CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
 PURCH_DATE DATE NULL, 
 DEL_DATE DATE   NULL, 
 CABIN_NAME CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (CABIN_TYPE)
 );

Comment: i am trying to insert/ update this table with the previous columns, however it is not recognizing the columns i am trying to insert

Comment: You need to change the insert statement or table definition. table doesnt have those columns i mentioned in comment. so its giving you the obvious error `unknown column`

Comment: i am trying to insert these into the table, im not sure how else i could do it.

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: Option 1 - Can you change table definition and include these columns `NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST` ? Ask DBA if  you cant. And once DBA adds these columns fire your insert. Option 2 - If you cant change table, ask data modeler - how to map `NAME, MAX, SIZE, PRICE, COST` to the columns from the `CABIN` table - for example Name should be mapped which column in CABIN table?

Comment: add DBMS tag too pls?